# Terminology - rebar "tie wire" or "tire wire"?

Tags: concrete, slab, rebar

This is about tie wire that is used in rebars in construction (e.g.: RCC beam and slab).

Sometimes I hear people say "tire wire" instead of "tie wire". Is "tire wire" a valid alternative terminology to "tie wire"? If it is, could someone provide links to prove its usage?

Thanks!

Comment: I have never heard the term tire wire.  I have heard folks with regional accents (southern drawl) pronounce it with a variation.

Comment: If they're legitimately calling it 'tire wire' it's because it's a laborious process. The term isn't official in any respects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It has always been "tie wire". Just do a search, that is all you will come up with.

Comment: Agree tie wire is what it is+